# How to draw a shape like this

Tags: flutter, dart, shapes, flutter-animation

I want to draw something like image below but I have no clue how to do this:(
I think I should use paint method to draw this.

using row and creating 2 container with decoration and circle shape(using box decoration and borderRadius) but I do Not know how to handle center shape between circles
.

[image: Image:]

Comment: You can try useing Stack but it wont be pixel perfect as image, customBorder(`OutlinedBorder` or `ShapeBorder`) might help.

Comment: You can use CustomPainter to achieve this.

Comment: @Malay Can you please help me to achieve this shape using CustomePainter?

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh, using stack is not suitable cuz it would not be exactly like the image

Comment: You can try using https://fluttershapemaker.com/.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`CustomPainter`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html). The code will be two circles with a line between them, and a Plus/Minus text within the cirlces.

##### Result

[image]

##### Example

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: CircleShapeWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



class CircleShapePainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Color(0xff3D3C3B)
      ..strokeWidth = 5
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(115, 100), 50, paint); // first circle
    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(230, 100), 50, paint); // second circle

    canvas.drawLine(Offset(140, 100), Offset(180, 100), paint); // line between circles

    // Draw "-" text in the first circle
    _drawText(canvas, "-", Offset(120, 100));

    // Draw "+" text in the second circle
    _drawText(canvas, "+", Offset(230, 100));
  }

  void _drawText(Canvas canvas, String text, Offset offset) {
    final textStyle = TextStyle(
      color: Colors.white,
      fontSize: 40,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    );
    final textPainter = TextPainter(
      text: TextSpan(text: text, style: textStyle),
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    );

    textPainter.layout(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: double.infinity);
    final offsetCentered = Offset(
      offset.dx - (textPainter.width / 2),
      offset.dy - (textPainter.height / 2),
    );
    textPainter.paint(canvas, offsetCentered);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}

class CircleShapeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint(
      painter: CircleShapePainter(),
      size: Size(200, 200),
    );
  }
}
```

##### Helpful resources

- [Custom painting in Flutter](https://youtu.be/vvI_NUXK00s)
- [Flutter Tutorial - Custom Paint - Draw Line, Square, Rect, Circle, Triangle, Arc & Image](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jaoJz3q9PmE)

Comment: Thanks for your answer bro. I have question, is it possible to handel on tab on these 2 circles?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [this tool](https://fluttershapemaker.com/). You can generate Flutter CustomPainter code from SVG. You can convert this image to SVG and paste the SVG code in this website. It will give you the code! I hope this will help you. If you have any issues in this process, you can ask.

Comment: '
//Copy this CustomPainter code to the Bottom of the File
class RPSCustomPainter extends CustomPainter {
    override
    void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
            
}

override
bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
}
};  it gave me some this code. and when I use it no thing appears on emulator

Comment: Can you send me the SVG code? I will try generating

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/gCYLC15   here is the link

Comment: This image is a bit blur and the custom painter is painting the plus sign in middle. It would be great if you could give me a high res image without the plus symbol. Otherwise the code is working for me.

Comment: unforchenetly It is not possible :(